# How do I reuse DataCacheFactory with Azure Caching (Co-Located)

Tags: c#, iis, azure, azure-caching

I have deployed an Azure WebRole with Co-located caching.
I am using the following default configuration for the clients.

```
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="[name]" />
  <!--<localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />-->
</dataCacheClient>
```

and currently I run the following code every time I access the Cache

`DataCacheFactory CacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
_Cache = CacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();`

This causes my Application Pool get terminated frequently. How `DataCacheFactory` and Re-use it whenever it is needed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you use the [ASP.NET Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to keep the DataChache Factory object.

You can write a helper class to get the Data Cache Factory object. Something like (never tested):

```
public class DataCacheHelper
{
    public DataCacheHelper()
    {
        DataCacheFactory factory = new DataCacheFactory();
        HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
        HttpContext.Current.Application["dcf"] = factory;
        HttpContext.Current.Application.Unock();
    }

    public DataCacheFactory GetFactory()
    {
        var factory = HttpContext.Current.Application["dcf"];
        if (factory == null)
        {
            factory = new DataCacheFactory();
            HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
            HttpContext.Current.Application["dcf"] = factory;
            HttpContext.Current.Application.Unock();
        }
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Or, if you are using ASP.NET MVC - you can create a base Controller class, which has GetCacheFactory method (which exactly what the helper method do), and have all your Controllers inherit this base instead the framework one. Same could be achieved for Web Forms.

Comment: Hi, currently I've implemented the same. The service was hosted on a Small Instance of Windows Server 2012. My code is `DataCache _cache = HttpContext.Current.Application["_sessionStore"] != null ? (DataCache)HttpContext.Current.Application["_sessionStore"] : SessionStore.Init();`

Comment: But still my Application pool gets terminated. I am not sure whether it is because of the memory usage or the simultaneous access of the Application Object